# How to change value in column based on the other table that is not related

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with column `num` that contain numbers from 10,000 to 1,000,000. This table need to be used as slicer.

Second Table contains `ClaimNumber` and `LossAmount` per each claim.

[image]

How can I generate a new dynamic column (or measure) that would decrease LossAmount per ClaimNumber based on number chosen in a slicer. Only, of course, if Loss Amount is greater than the `num` column.

For example if I chose 40,000 then all Claims that have LossAmount more than 40,000 need to be equal 40,000.

On a picture below you see, that choosing 40,000 cap Claim5 and Claim7 became 40,000.

Is it possible to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to do this as a measure since a calculated column cannot be responsive to slicers.

The measure should be fairly simple.

```
Capped Loss Amount =
VAR MaxLoss = MAX(Slicer[num])
RETURN
SUMX(
    Claims,
    IF(
        Claims[LossAmount] > MaxLoss,
        MaxLoss,
        Claims[LossAmount]
    )
)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!